# is there any way to loop through a set of posted variables, checking if they are set?

Tags: php, html, post, error-handling, submit

My current code would be long winded and repetitive, is there any way that I can loop through the posted variables and check to see if they are set using the isset() function.

Here is my code:

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['qty'];
$model = $_POST['mdl'];
$weight = $_POST['wgt'];
$repornew = $_POST['ron'];
$date = $_POST['dob'];
$spec = $_POST['spc'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
//retreive all values posted by user

if(isset($item_name) || isset($quantity) || isset($model) || isset($weight) || isset($repornew) || isset($date) || isset($spec) || isset($description)){

//send error back to user
}
```

Would using an array be a good idea, or even JSON to solve the problem?

I get the general idea of what I need to do, but what to use as the implementation is the thing that is bugging me.

Cheers

Comment: why the -1? constructive critisicm please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through the POST variables and check if they were submitted:

```
$vars = array('item_name','qty','mdl','wgt','ron','dob','spc','desc');
$ok = 1;
foreach ($vars as $value) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$value]])) $ok = 0;
}

if (!$ok) echo 'Not everything is set!';
else echo 'Alright! Everything\'s right!';
```

Comment: i've implemented this code, changed it obviously to suite my code, but thanks a lot for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

```php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this:

```
$required_keys = array('keys','you','require');
$entered_keys = array_keys($_POST);

if (count(array_diff($required_keys,$entered_keys)) == 0) {
  // everything entered
} else {
  // something missing
}
```